# How to add an independent loading state for each item of the list?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a payment methods screen with a simple list and a delete action button on each element:

```js
const PaymentIndexScreen = ({ navigation }: Props): ReactElement => {
  const [creditCards, setCreditCards] = useState<CreditCard[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
    client.service('credit-cards').find().then((result) => {
      setCreditCards(result.data.map((creditCardData) => {
        const year = creditCardData.expirationDate.slice(2);
        const month = creditCardData.expirationDate.slice(0, 2);

        return {
          ...creditCardData,
          expirationDate: `${month}/${year}`,
          loading: false,
        };
      }));
    });
  }), [navigation]);

  const handleDelete = (selectedCard): void => {
    console.log(selectedCard);
    selectedCard.loading = true;
    Alert.alert(
      'Delete?',
      null,
      [
        {
          text: 'Cancel'
        },
        {
          text: 'Delete',
          onPress: () => client.service('credit-cards').remove(selectedCard._id)
            .then(() => setCreditCards(creditCards.filter((card) => card._id !== selectedCard._id)))
            .catch(handleClientError)
          ,
        },
      ],
    );
  };

  return (
    <ScreenWrapper>
      <ScreenHeader
        title="Payment"
        navigation={navigation}
      />
      <ScrollView>
        <ScreenTitle label="Payment methods" />
        {creditCards.length > 0
          ? creditCards.map((card) => (
            <ListItem
              key={card._id}
              title={`●●●● ●●●● ●●●● ${card.lastDigits}`}
              content={`Expire on ${card.expirationDate}.`}
              onDelete={() => {handleDelete(card)}}
              disabled={card.loading}
            />
          ))
          : (
            <Banner
              iconName="credit-card"
              text="No payment method"
            />
          )}
      </ScrollView>
      <View>
        <Button
          title="Add"
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Add')}
        />
      </View>
    </ScreenWrapper>
  );
};

export default PaymentIndexScreen;
```

The delete action works **except the loading state change**.

It looks like changing the `card.loading` property does trigger any rendering.

The only solution I see is to entirely replace the created array (like I did for deletion) with the updated item included, but I found this very heavy and might (not?) lead to performance issue.

What is the best way to implement an independent loading state without rewriting the entire array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me from the code you put that the approach to handling the state of the list needs to be corrected when some events occur. I believe that a possible solution would be to abstract into an exclusive function that can handle the state of each line.

Example ([Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/handling-states-example-with-data-fetching-w9m27?file=/src/App.js)):

```js
    const handleData = (item, newState) =>
    setData((prevData) =>
      prevData.map((prevItem) => {
        if (item.index === prevItem.index) return { ...prevItem, ...newState };
        return prevItem;
      })
    );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the sandbox really helped!

So there is no other choice than rewriting the entire array, got that.

Comment: This is a simple approach for state management. There is a different approach for state management using Redux + Immer (https://github.com/immerjs/immer), but I don't think that will be useful for your application right now. Immer handles a lot of the tree change in the state under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

React re-renders a component when its props or state change. In your case, neither is changing. Note that for react to trigger changes, state/props has to be changed immutably.

In your case, you will need to use `setCreditCards` to change your array in your `handleDelete` function.

```js
setCreditCards(
  creditCards.map(creditCard => {
    if (creditCard._id === selectedCard._id) {
      // return selectedCard with loading set to true
      return {
        ...selectedCard,
        loading: true,
      };
      // Return the card
    }
    return creditCard;
  }),
);
```

This will generally not cause a performance issue unless your list is really large, time complexity is O(n). In that case, you will probably consider lazy loading or loading partial data anyway.